# Implement a LINQ Expression parameter

Tags: c#, linq

I am using an interface I found, which has a method that takes a LINQ expression as a parameter.
How would I implement this method to use the LINQ Expression? I can see it being very useful, but dont how to write the code to use it!!

Its a repository interface.

signature is...

```
IQueryable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> criteria);
```

Comment: You mean you want to write your own method that accepts an Expression as a parameter? Or you want to use an existing methond on someone else's interface?

Comment: I want to write the method that accepts an Expression as a parameter.
Thx Rup

Comment: I'm confused; the signature you've shown *demonstrates* how to accept an `Expression` as a parameter...

Comment: but I dont know how to write the code in the method that uses the expression passed in.

I am implementing an interface, which has this method.  But how do I write the C# to use the expression?
Thx

Comment: You have a two good examples already. However if they are not working for you let us know and why in the comments of the questions.  May if you where more clear on what you want the method to do exactly it could be more helpful.   You can look at the MSDN doc's on what you can do with an Expression for details and use the examples below as a guide.  

Basically.... What is it "getting" and where is it "getting" it from and you want to use the expression as criteria against what?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for something like this:

```
List<T> myList = new List<T>();
...
public IQueryable<int> Get(Expression<Func<int, bool>> criteria)
{
    return myList.Where(criteria.Compile()).AsQueryable();
}
```

This passes your expression `criteria` to the linq-method [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx).  You can then call it like this:

```
foreach(var something in myClass.Get(o => o.someProperty == 10))
{
    ...
}
```

Of course, this is pretty stupid; it would be better to just implement `IEnumerable<T>`...

Comment: Today you would probably avoid calling `.Compile()`, which converts `Expression<Func<T>>` to `Func<T>`. If someone asks for the former, they probably have a use or need for it. Such a defect could be unseen for some time, for example it might work in a memory repository but fail when using a SQL repository.

Answer (score 6):

`IQueryable<T>` has an `.Where()` overload that takes an `Expression<Func<T>>` parameter. When assuming that this is a Linq2Sql or Linq2Entities repository, something like this should work

```
class MyRepository
{
    ObjectContext context = // initialize somehow;


    public IQueryable<int> Get(Expression<Func<int, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return context.SomeObject.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

If that's not the case, and you only have an enumerable, you can use `AsQuerably()` as the first step in the chain to convert it to IQuerably, giving you the option to use the expression based predicate:

```
public IQueryable<int> Get(Expression<Func<int, bool>> predicate)
{
    return mySimpleList.AsQuerable().Where(predicate);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I gave the bounty to BlueRaja, just because it was the first answer...thanks though, its very helpful

Comment: I think (not 100% sure though) that the `.Compile` followed by `.AsQueryable` is far worse performance wise if you're using a database. With linq2sql or linq2entities I think it will fetch all and perform the predicate in C# rather than in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

That is a predicate expression; something that indicates data to include.

So, to get a single record you could use:

```
int rowId = 123;
var row = foo.Get(x => x.Id == rowId).Single();
```

Or to get all data matching some condition you could use:

```
var allDeleted = foo.Get(x => x.IsDeleted).ToList();
```

Note that this should be composable, for more fun:

```
var today = from row in foo.Get(x => x.DateCreated > DateTime.Today)
            orderby row.Name
            select new {row.Id, row.Name};
```

Comment: Thx Mark, I'm OK with using the predicates, i just don't know how the write the method that accepts the predicate.
Thx